# Trouble with Go Routines and its concurrency

Tags: go, broker

TL;DR accepting and connecting two separate SETS of connections. Want to do it with RPC concurrently.

I'm attempting to create semi distributed system on my computer. The piece of the code I'm working on right now is something like a broker node, in other words it is always accepting client connections from a port. Its also constantly accepting back end node connections from a different port. 
I'm trying to find a way to concurrently listen for both, and serve both. I'm using RPC and the way I tried doing it is this:
Main:

```
func main(){  
 ...  
 rpc.Register(myInterface)  
 l, err := net.Listen("tcp", client_port)  
 if err != nil {...}  
 go handleClients(l)  
 node_l, err := net.Listen("tcp", node_port)  
 if err != nil{...}   
 go setUpIncomingNodes(node_l, chan)  
 for{// add nodes to a list from chan} 
}
```

Concurrent functions:

```
// Adds clients to be connected
func handleClients(listener net.Listener){
 for{
  conn, err :=listener.Accept()
  if err != nil{...}
  // Starts up a blocking (on that thread) RPC connection
  go rpc.serveConn(conn)
 }
}
func setUpIncomingNodes(node_listener net.Listener, incoming_nodes chan<- net.Conn){
 for{
  conn, err := node_listener.Accept()
  if err != nil{...}
  incoming_nodes <- conn     
 }
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't serve the first node, until the second comes along. I can't understand why. Also it seems that only one connection can happen at time, but I thought RPC served on a different port (thus not blocking it). Any help is super appreciated.

I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.badgerr.co.uk/2011/06/20/golang-away-tcp-chat-server/) but I found the circumstance too different, its also using a different version of Go. I use two types of nodes/connections where Type A needs to be served through the broker to Type B.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, goroutine are like fibers, and do some kind of cooperative multitasking. It seems to me that your current implementation locks itself. I hope this comment gives a clue---dunno the Go semantics enough to tell more at this point.

Comment: You are correct: goroutines do cooperative multithreading at an abstract level above OS threads. In other words, each OS thread can be apparently running many goroutines concurrently. The Go runtime does this by time-slicing the goroutines onto the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Then, I think the call to `Accept` is blocking the thread, so all goroutines. There is need to either yield execution, or change for actual threads or channels.

Comment: What is the 'best practice' form of doing this? Timeout's? I feel like that wouldn't work either since it would go from `Accept` to the other `Accept` and possibly miss connections from one or the other.

Comment: @EricPlaton: goroutines are cooperative in a sense, but the only way for one to block the entire program is to have a busy loop with GOMAXPROCS=1 (and even then you wouldn't get the deadlock error).

Comment: @jQwierdy: you need to show a little more code to sort this out, like how to you define your channels, and what does you main for loop look like?

Comment: @JimB my channel was just a buffered channel of net.Conn. See my answer below, I figured it out. Thanks for your help! After you said that goroutines are cooperative (Which I thought but then was convinced I was wrong) I sought to figure out a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I think the issue was that I was attempting to **pass** in listeners to the *Go routine*, thus having each go routine having a dependancy with the main thread. The working solution ended up being as simple as this:

```
func main(){
 ...
 node_ip_port := "127.0.0.1:9000"
 client_ip_port := "127.0.0.1:1000"
 nodeChan := make(chan net.Conn, 20)

 go func(ip_port string, nodeChan chan<- net.Conn) {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", node_ip)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Had an error connecting to node", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, _ := l.Accept()
        kvChan <- conn
    }
  }(node_ip_port, nodeChan)

 go func(ip_port string) {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ip_port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Had an error connecting to client", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, _ := l.Accept()
        go rpc.ServeConn(conn)
    }
  }(client_ip_port)
  // List of connected nodes
  nodeList := list.New()
  for {
    node := <-nodeChan
    nodeList.PushBack(node)
    // My RPC functions use the nodes in this list to serve :-)
  }
 }
```